# How to separate one column in dataframe into many? [python, pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I have in mind is converting a dataframe like this:

| Letters |
| --- |
| A; B; C |
| B; C |
| A; B; C |
| A |
| B |

Into this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |

Any ideas on how to do that? I have been able to split the column based on "; ", but I have no idea how to categorize them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `get_dummies`

```
out = df.Letters.str.get_dummies('; ')
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  0  1  1
2  1  1  1
3  1  0  0
4  0  1  0
```